# Failed to acquire ms graph token

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I have problem while trying to acquire the ms graph access token without a user.

I login from code using the quickstart provided settings

```
    IConfidentialClientApplication app;
    app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("<application client ID>")
                                              .WithClientSecret("<application secret>")
                                              .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant ID>"))
                                              .Build();
    
    var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new List<string>() { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" })
                      .ExecuteAsync();

    HttpClient sender = new HttpClient();
    sender.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
              "Authorization",
               String.Format("Bearer " + result.AccessToken)
               );
    HttpResponseMessage meResult = await sender.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<email adress>/photo/$value");
    string context =await  meResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("WAAA");
```

Basically the problem is that I can aquire a token before creating the HTTP client, but when I would like to use it to get the user photo the response is 401 :(
With the message: `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials` The Azure application has these permissions granted to them.

[image]

Can anybody spot what am I missing?

Comment: Which permission do you have on your Azure portal? You should have `Application User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All` permission and afterwords need to add `Grant admin consent`.

Comment: I would only like to read the profile picture of the users. Therefore I am quite sure i don't need read write. As far as I read in the docs the picture is a basic information which only requires the basic version to be granted.

Comment: I got it see the answer and set `User.Read.All`  application permission

Comment: You should take your received token, paste it at https://jwt.io and check if it really contains the desired claims or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which permission do you have on your Azure portal? I guess you have now `Delegated permission` only.

You should have `User.Read.All` `Application  permission` and afterwords need to add Grant admin consent. It should be like below:

You can get details here in our [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions)

***`Permission:`***

[image]

Once you set the permission you can get below output:

***`Output:`***

[image]

***`Postman Test Result:`***

[image]

***`Azure profile Pciture:`***

[image]

> ***Note:*** Your context required `Application permission` but seems you have `Delegated Permission` only.

Hope that would help.